# Javascript function to allow time input between range(08 - 15), or a default (in range) time in textbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the dateTimePicker jQuery plugin from this site: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker

In my field I use date + time with a format of  `format:'d/m/Y H:i'` .

I have set allowTimes from 08:00 to 15:00 and works fine. However, if you choose a date, it automatically displays the current time (16.30) even though that the allowed times are between 08:00 to 15:00. How to set a default time, or the maximum time, anything between the allowed range?
Thank you.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
onShow: function(){
this.setOptions({ minDate: output });
},



onGenerate:function( ct ){
        $(this).find('.xdsoft_date.xdsoft_weekend')
            .addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
    },
    weekends:['01.01.2014','02.01.2014','03.01.2014','04.01.2014','05.01.2014','06.01.2014'],
    format:'d/m/Y H:i',
    minDate:'0',
    validateOnBlur: false,
    minTime:'08:00',
    maxTime:'15:00',
    dayOfWeekStart:'1',
    allowTimes:[
  '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00'
 ]


});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That plugin has a `onChangeDateTime` event handler, so you could add something like this to your datepicker options:

```
onChangeDateTime:function(db,$input){
    var time = $input.val();
    // Now use some if logic to determine if the time has minutes
    // And if it does change the time to the closest appropriate.
}
```

This function should be called immediately after a date is picked, and if the current time from that date value is outside of your desired range, you can change it here and the user will never see the invalid current-time.